# have problem when i handle vue3 refs array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have problem when I handle vue3 refs.

I get data from firestore.

I log [documents], and it works fine.

But when I get value from document's fist array

for example,

value I wanted : `abc1 (first array's displayName)`

so I tried

```
console log

0. documents (works, results below)


1. documents.value.displayName (error)

2. documents.value[0].displayName (error)
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at setup (Write.vue?125b:56)
```

but failed.

How could i get value from refs array?

```
Log document

RefImpl {_shallow: false, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: null, _value: null}
__v_isRef: true
_rawValue: Array(2)
0: {displayName: "abc1", orgName: "amazon", email: "aaa@aaa.com", regDate2: "2021-7-27", …}
1: {displayName: "abc2", email: "aaa@aaa.com", orgName: "google", …}
```

**setup Fucntion**

```
    setup() {
      const title = ref('')
      const contents = ref('')
      const { user } = getUser()
      const userUid = user.value.uid
      const { documents } = getCollection('user')
      console.log(documents, 'documents log')
      console.log(documents.value[0].displayName, 'documents value log')
      return {title, contents, user, documents }
    }
```

**getCollection.js**

```
const getCollection = (collection, query) => {

  const documents = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  // register the firestore collection reference
  let collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection)

  if (query) {
    collectionRef = collectionRef.where(...query)
  }

  const unsub = collectionRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
    let results = []
    snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
      results.push({...doc.data()})
    });
    
    // update values
    documents.value = results
    error.value = null
  }, err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    documents.value = null
    error.value = 'could not fetch the data'
  })

  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => unsub());
  });

  return { error, documents }
}

export default getCollection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCollection` updates `documents` asynchronously *after* you've logged it to the console. Note that `console.log` logs a *live reference* to the object, so you'll see the most recent value in the browser console instead of the actual value at the time you logged it. If you want to see the actual value, `JSON.stringify` it:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    //...                
    console.log(JSON.stringify(documents.value), 'documents log')
  }
}
```

The log shown above will likely log `null`, as the ref has not been updated yet.

### Solution

To log the first element's `displayName` in `documents`, use a [`watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch) on the `documents` ref, which will be invoked when the `documents.value` is updated:

```js
import { watch } from 'vue'
 
export default {
  setup() {
    const { documents } = getCollection('user')

    watch(documents,
          newValue => {
            console.log(newValue?.[0].displayName)
          },

          // use `deep` flag to observe property changes to array elements
          { deep: true }
    )
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-log-async-ref?file=src/App.vue)